# equivalente ao scanf/gets para java

Tags: java

bom pessoal eu estou apendendo programar em java e minha duvida é o seguinte, em linguagem C aprendi que para o usuario digitar alguma coisa é usado a função scanf/gets e no java qual seria??

eu dei uma pesquisada por ai e achei isso

```
package br.com.treinaweb.parte2;

import java.util.Scanner;/*essa linha*/ 

public class fluxo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);/*essa linha*/
  int nota;

  System.out.println ("Insira o numero");  

  nota=leitor.nextInt(); /*essa linha*/



    System.out.println(nota >= 7 ? "Aprovado" : "Reprovado");

  }

}
```

tem algum modo mais facil de fazer isso? pois nao creio que terei q usar 2 linhas de codigo pra fazer uma coisa só.

Comment: Você usa uma linha de código apenas pra realizar a leitura. A outra é pra instanciar o leitor. Em C, você usa o `#include <stdio.h>` pra incluir a biblioteca, e o `scanf` para ler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No JAVA o melhor meio de fazer isso é realmente utilizando a classe Scanner.
O significado da classe Scanner para muitos no começo é um pouco complicado de entender, mas com o tempo o programador acaba se acostumando com a sua definição. Um scanner de texto simples pode analisar os tipos primitivos e strings usando expressões regulares.

A classe Scanner tem como objetivo separar a entrada dos textos em blocos, gerando os conhecidos tokens, que são sequências de caracteres separados por delimitadores que por padrão correspondem aos espaços em branco, tabulações e mudança de linha.

Com essa classe podem ser convertidos textos para tipos primitivos, sendo que esses textos podem ser considerados como objetos do tipo String, InputStream e arquivos.

Na Prática:
Antes de tudo, é necessário saber algumas funções e aspectos que essa classe tem para exercer o funcionamento dentro do esperado. Quando invocada a classe Scanner, o compilador pedirá para fazer a seguinte importação:

Listagem 1: Importando a classe Scanner

import java.util.Scanner;

Como descrito na introdução, essa classe ajuda na leitura dos dados informados. Para fazer essa ação na prática, é necessário criar um objeto do tipo Scanner que passa como argumento o objeto System.in dentro construtor, do seguinte modo:

Listagem 2: Declarações do Scanner

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class TestaDeclaracaoScanner {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Lê a partir da linha de comando
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String textoString = "Maria Silva";
    //Lê a partir de uma String
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(textoString); 
}
}
```

Listagem 3: Contagem de tokens em uma string

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContaTokens {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Digite um texto:");
    while(sc.hasNext()){
        i++;
        System.out.println("Token: "+sc.next());
    }
    sc.close(); //Encerra o programa
}
}
```

O objeto System.in é o que faz a leitura do que se escreve no teclado. Veja abaixo como são invocados alguns dos métodos principais que correspondem com a assinatura que retorna um valor do tipo que foi invocado. Ou seja, para cada um dos primitivos existe uma chamada do método para retornar o valor especificado na entrada de dados, sempre seguindo o formato nextTipoDado().

Listagem 4: Métodos invocados da classe Scanner

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    float numF = sc.nextFloat();
    int num1 = sc.nextInt();
    byte byte1 = sc.nextByte();
    long lg1 = sc.nextLong();
    boolean b1 = sc.nextBoolean();
    double num2 = sc.nextDouble();
    String nome = sc.nextLine();
```

Como a classe Scanner trabalha com entrada de dados, sempre é uma boa prática fazer o uso do try/catch para que os sistemas fiquem bem construídos.

Comment: humm ok obrigado cara voce ajudou bastante =)